# React download for offline usage

Tags: reactjs

I want to download and use react on a network that has no Internet connectivity. I downloaed the zipped source code file at bottom of this page. https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v16.8.6

It does not seem as straight forward as when you download jquery.js and simply point to it like `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`. What is the correct way to utilize react on offline network and how should I be pointing to the correct js "src" files? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to DONWLOAD and include all of the following

```
react : https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js
react-dom : https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js
babel : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js
```

Include these inside your html file

```
<script src="react.production.min.js" />
<script src="react-dom.production.min.js" />
<script src="babel.min.js" />

<!-- Your react scripts that you will be coding in -->
<script src="my-script.js" />
```

Then set up a div with some id in your same html file .

```
<div id="root" />
```

In your my-script.js code add some react and render it to the div like this

```
function MyFirstReactComponent(){
    return <div> My First React Component ! </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(     
  <MyFirstReactComponent />,
  document.getElementById('root')        
);
```

**This should work for you!**

> The key hear is the addition of Babel  which
>   transforms your react code(JSX) to browser understandable Javascript. Also
>   important, the 'ReactDOM' lib which is react's way of interacting with the browser's DOM API.

Answer (score 0):

Include these inside your html file

```
<script src="../babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="../react.development.js"></scriptt>
   <script src="../react-dom.development.js"></script>

       <script type="text/babel src="Your js file source">
```